# python - calling a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

In my below Python code, why cannot I call the function by the second method? If I would like to change the code such that I can call the function using the second method, how should I change my function?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
sales = {'Feb': [200, None, None],'Mar': [140, 215, 95]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)

def impute_age(cols):
    Age = cols[0]
    Pclass = cols[1]

    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 215:
            return 37
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
        else:
            return 24
    else:
        return Age


#method 1
df['z'] = df[['Feb','Mar']].apply(impute_age, axis=1)

print(df)
#method 2
df['zz'] = impute_age(df[['Feb','Mar']])
```

---

```
type(df[['Feb','Mar']].head(1))
Out[7]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(df[['Feb','Mar']].head(1).values[0])
Out[8]: numpy.ndarray
```

Bharath Shetty's comment below helped me. The function expects at array as input and not a dataframe. The columns of a data frame cannot be accessed using df[0]...that gives an error as below

```
df[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-9ae93f22b889>", line 1, in <module>
    df[0]

  File "C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2062, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)

  File "C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2069, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)

  File "C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1534, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)

  File "C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)

  File "C:\Users\nikhi\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflowspyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2395, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5239)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5085)

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1207, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20405)

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1215, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20359)

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: The first method is much more performant. I wonder why you want to call the second way.

Comment: Silly question. You're passing one item at a time in the first method using `apply` and you're passing an entire column through the second method. What is `cols[0]` equal to if you're passing an entire column. The answer to your question is by using method 1

Comment: i am not passing an entire column `df[['Feb','Mar']]` is a dataframe...i know method1 is better. I would like to know why method 2 doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a function across the columns is not the same as passing the dataframe to that function. `Apply` is a simplified for loop. It sends every row one at a time to the function collect the data and then return a series.

To make your 2nd method work use `iterrows` inside the function with help of an empty list to collect the data  i.e

```
def impute_age2(cols):
    k = []
    for _,i in cols.iterrows():
        Age = i[0]
        Pclass = i[1]
        if pd.isnull(Age):
            if Pclass == 215:
                k.append(37)
            elif Pclass == 2:
                k.append(29)
            else:
                k.append(24)
        else:
            k.append(Age)
    return k

df['zz'] = impute_age(df[['Feb','Mar']])
```

Output:

```
     Feb  Mar     zz   
0  200.0  140  200.0
1    NaN  215   37.0 
2    NaN   95   24.0
```

Comment: if `apply` sends one row at a time then why cannot i use `df['zz'] = impute_age(df[['Feb','Mar']].head(1))`

Comment: Thats because you are sending dataframe as the parameter to function, and it isn't a list or series to access with help of index. If you say col[0] it will search for the column in df with name `0`.

Comment: If you want to get the first value then pass the argument as a list or an array i.e `impute_age2(df[['Feb','Mar']].head(1).values[0]`. To get all the values then certainly a for loop.